# Put Flashlight To Ear

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

A dictionary entry for "to" has this usage [example](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/to) of the phrase "put ...to":

> 1. He ***put*** a finger ***to*** his lips.

But, on the web, I found sentences that uses "put...to" this way:

> 2. Jane ***put*** a flashlight ***to*** John's ear.

Does it mean Jane really touched John's ear with a flashlight?  The purpose of a flashlight to shine light at something.   Could sentence 2 have other meanings?

Comment: Note that "put to X" does not necessarily mean actually touching, it could mean bringing very close. It is quite plausible that someone would hold a flashlight very near a person's ear so they could see the ear canal.

Answer (score 1):

'Jane put a flashlight to Johns ear'

Without context it's hard to know the authors intention, but

1)  Jane used the flashlight to illuminate inside the ear ( maybe to look for an irritant )

2) John had big ears, and so holding a (strong) flashlight to the ear would allow Jane to partially see through it (medical/comical reasons)

3) Jane was making John aware, through some proactive method, he should be listening carefully. The flashlight is a metaphor. (This would most likely be used in literature rather than in speech).

There are probably better ways to express the above actions, but the use of 'put' and 'to' creates a more intimate scenario than maybe replacing it with 'pointed' or 'aimed'.

Answer (score 0):

> 2) Jane **put** a flashlight **to** John's ear.

literally means as you say, the flashlight actually touching or close to touching his ear. A similar example:

> Jane **put** the seashell **to** her ear.

Here, the seashell was touching her ear or at least close enough to hear the waves.

To say the likely meaning of pointing the flashlight (light) at his ear, you have to say a bit more. For example:

> Jane **pointed** a flashlight **at** John's ear.

Use *at* because it is a direction the light travels, not the physical position of the flashlight that you are trying to describe.

Comment: So, "to **put** a flashlight **to** someone's ear" is poor English?

Comment: Depends on the context, but it implies it is physically put at or near to the ear. Of course its possible...